# Mail::queue() doesn't send email when queue:listen is triggered

Tags: php, laravel, email, queue, laravel-5

I am trying to make a mail system for my website using laravel 5.2 to broadcast a mail for all users.

When I use `Mail::send()` method I get this working and no errors found.

But when I use `Mail::queue()` method and then get the queue listener works, The mail doesn't seem to be sent.

I have setup a queue as mentioned in Laravel 5.2 and in Jobs table in side my database I notice that nothing is changed except the attemp field which incremented over time.

Can any one help me to get my queue mail system work ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you run the worker? https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queues#running-the-queue-worker

Comment: Silly question: Do you have a mailserver running on the host machine?

Comment: @JeremyHarris I used artizan command queue:listen and inside database attemp counter is incremented every couple of seconds, but nothing happen

Comment: No, I was saying *my* question was silly. But it appears that you don't really know for certain, so I'll ask again a little differently: Is your server running a mail server? If not, are you sending your mail through an SMTP service? If neither of those are true, then of course it would stand to reason that your mail isn't getting sent, because there is no service - local or otherwise - that is actually sending it.

Comment: @maiorano84 any help :)